# gclient issue when building Chromium on Windows

Tags: chromium, gclient

I'm following steps on https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md to build Chromium on Windows, when it comes to run **gclient**, it gives following usage information, it seems something is wrong, any suggestion is appreciated.

C:\Users\Test>gclient

Usage: gclient.py  [options]

Meta checkout dependency manager for Git.

Commands are:
config   creates a .gclient file in the current directory
diff     displays local diff for every dependencies
fetch    fetches upstream commits for all modules
flatten  flattens the solutions into a single DEPS file
getdep   gets revision information and variable values from a DEPS file
grep     greps through git repos managed by gclient
help     prints list of commands or help for a specific command
metrics  reports, and optionally modifies, the status of metric collection
pack     generates a patch which can be applied at the root of the tree
recurse  operates [command args ...] on all the dependencies
revert   reverts all modifications in every dependencies
revinfo  outputs revision info mapping for the client and its dependencies
root     outputs the solution root (or current dir if there isn't one)
runhooks runs hooks for files that have been modified in the local working copy
setdep   modifies dependency revisions and variable values in a DEPS file
status   shows modification status for every dependencies
sync     checkout/update all modules
validate validates the .gclient and DEPS syntax
verify   verifies the DEPS file deps are only from allowed_hosts

Options:
--version             show program's version number and exit
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
-j JOBS, --jobs=JOBS  Specify how many SCM commands can run in parallel;
defaults to 8 on this machine
-v, --verbose         Produces additional output for diagnostics. Can be
used up to three times for more logging info.
--gclientfile=CONFIG_FILENAME
Specify an alternate .gclient file
--spec=SPEC           create a gclient file containing the provided string.
Due to Cygwin/Python brokenness, it can't contain any
newlines.
--no-nag-max          Ignored for backwards compatibility.

Comment: What error message do you see when doing so?

Comment: when i run **gclient** it should download and install git, python and stuff, but it shows gclient usage help as i pasted above.

Comment: Never came across this issue before. Maybe try setting up from scratch agan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try it in a clean system, it works.